# Alpine Linux - find nouser and nogroup keywords not working

Tags: find, alpine-linux

I want to find unowned and ungrouped files. On other Linux distributions, I use

```
find / -user nouser
find / -group nogroup
```

But, the above does not work in Alpine Linux? What are the alternate commands?

I also tried

```
find / -nouser
find / -nogroup
```

This does not work as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

"Alpine Linux is a security-oriented, lightweight Linux distribution based on musl libc and busybox." You are using Busybox's find, which does not support the `-nouser` or `-nogroup` predicates. To use these, you need to install a real find program.